# What does actually happens on tile hashing

Tags: algorithms, space-complexity, reinforcement-learning

I am going through Richard Sutton book about Reinforcement Learning and I just encountered the tile coding method. I understood pretty well the principles, however, at the very end of the section, tile hashing is mentionned.

> Hashing produces tiles consisting of noncontiguous, disjoint regions ran-
>   domly spread throughout the state space,  but that still form an exhaustive
>   partition.  [...]  Through hashing, memory requirements are often reduced by large
>   factors with little loss of performance.  This is possible because high resolution
>   is needed in only a small fraction of the state space.

I understand how hashing can consequently limit memory requirement, but I cannot visualize how hashing would work for tile coding. How can collisions be handled if tiles are spread randomly ? How are the tilings represented then ?

I have been doing some research, however, most of the ressources lead directly to the mentionned book.